# How do I backport Mesa on Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, compiling, backports

This post is continuing a previous one where I tried to compile Mesa 10.0.5:
[What are the required build dependencies of mesa for Debian-based distros?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162807/what-are-the-required-build-dependencies-of-mesa-for-debian-based-distros) . Except that this time, I switched to another almost same laptop and to Debian 7.6.

Furthermore, during his helpings Faheem Mitha also bumped on the bad libdrm_nouveau version (0.6 while installed is 2.4.40). So now the question before mine's now is "why is this happening ?" with that, here's more details about it: [What is the correct way to fix the configure error: "Requested 'libdrm_nouveau >= 2.4.33' but version of libdrm_nouveau is 0.6"?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164554)

My target is about playing Team Fortress 2 Debian 7.6 since a long time now, but couldn't because of the following graphical glitches:

- Bad dark textures
- Very low FPS
- Low brightness
- Green texture on training video
- Ugly grain effect on textures

The solution after a lot of research was to backport Mesa. The problem is that I'm just really new on how to do it.

So the question is: How to backport Mesa on Debian 7.6 in the most stable way ? (Meaning by the same logic with the less compilations possible).

PS: I managed to determine that the latest version I can have without apparently recompile a lot is 10.0.5. If there is another version with even less compilation/building, I'll stick to it. Stability first ! Since I also virtualize a lot with 3D enabled :)

PS2: I was hinted about not doing any local install and backporting Mesa 10 from testing. But the problem remains the same since I don't really know how to do it.

PS3: I also ran into a weird problem that prevents me to compile Mesa. After a while, it says me that libdrm_nouveau is version 0.6, even if my libdrm_nouveau package is 2.4.40 ! How is it possible ?

PS4: By the way, is it recommended to redo the steps at every kernel updates ?

Here's my computer:

- Core I5 with HD 3000 and an nVidia 610M
- Fresh Debian 7.6 updated
- Kernel 3.14 i686-pae with nvidia 331.67 kernel modules from Wheezy-Backports
- bumblebee-nvidia installed through wheezy-backports repository

Comment: This should be straightforward. I'll try to answer it tomorrow.

Comment: There are a bunch of options here - http://snapshot.debian.org/package/mesa/. I suggest you pick the oldest which will satisfy your requirements. The older it is, the closer it will be to wheezy, and the easier to build.

Comment: I've tried using them, but there's breakages everywhere and even the Mesa right after (9.1.6) needs libc6 2.17 at least. I've used the jessie repository (20131007T160010Z) since wheezy and wheezy-backports shows nothing to upgrade even if with the latest snapshot (20141014T114823Z).
I think It will be mandatory to backport it manually.

Comment: You need to rebuild/recompile it on your system. If you tell me which version you want, I can attempt to do so on my system, and if it works, I'll write instructions for you to do so.

Comment: Thank you very much :) So, let's do the 10.0.5 since it's the last version that doesn't require a lot of compilations.

Comment: Maybe something like 9.1.6 would be more manageable. Would that be useful to you? I'm asking what is the oldest version that would still satisfy your requirements. Clearly the wheezy version does not, so that gives a lower bound.

Comment: 9.1.6 is okay too :D

Comment: I tried `9.1.3`, on the theory that the oldest one would be the likeliest to succeed, but got `configure: error: Package requirements (libdrm_nouveau >= 2.4.33) were not met:

Requested 'libdrm_nouveau >= 2.4.33' but version of libdrm_nouveau is 0.6

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.` The good news is, it's not just you. I'm still not clear what was causing this bug. Let me poke around. Can you tell me what version of mesa you need exactly? I.e. I need mesa >= version_num.

Comment: And if possible, let me know why you think it fixes your problem.

Comment: I need a newer version above  9.1.0 (otherwise garbled UI -> http://www.mesa3d.org/relnotes/9.1.1.html), I prefer 10.0.5 but if one version is easier for you I'll stick to it. On the previous question, you talked with Braim who said that the libdrm_nouveau version 0.6 is a known problem. Here's a link where Robert Hooker explain it: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=26784
.
I think it will fix my problem since I think it's a driver issue, and that people are aware of this problem and managed to solve it: https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Team_Fortress_2

Comment: [https://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2013/03/msg00014.html] [http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=190&p=696973]
I've tried all the procedures where the people managed to succeed, but yet failed since my knowledges about this is limited. Th best guide I found is this one, but also failed: https://lists.debian.org/debian-x/2013/03/msg00014.html
It's also look like an OpenGL version problem too: [http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2116921&s=c7bbe7d16d4bd65a173d5409442da2e4]

Comment: And most of all, the last Mesa provided in SteamOS (based on Debian Wheezy) is: 10.0.1
http://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=steamos

Comment: Ok, so anything after 9.1.0 is Ok. Got it. 10 may be possible, but better to try 9.x first. I don't understand Robert Hooker's explanation. Maybe I'll ask here. Asking him would also be a possibility, I suppose.

Comment: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=668684

Here's the Robert Hooker's explanation again, but this time it's the original post with the diff made to fix that problem. Check for the only line where "0.6" is present on the cgit commit link, which seems to be "simply" replaced with 2.4.33. Since Debian Wheezy ships 2.4.40, is it safe to modify libdrm_nouveau.pc from 0.6 and make it "lie" to 2.4.40 ?

Comment: Any news about the backporting ?

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't got around to posting a question about this. I'll try to do so today.

Comment: Did you have some news about this libdrm problem ? Meanwhile, I tried to install Mesa 9.2.2 from the Parsix (distribution based on Wheezy stable) repositories. So far, even glxheads shows me the correct version of Mesa and openGL. But, when I ran steam, it says me that: "OpenGL GLX context is not using direct rendering..., doing "LIBGL_DEBUG=verbose /usr/bin/steam-debian" showed me: "ERROR: nss_util.cc(1018)] Failed to load NSS libraries." Which is wrong since I have libnss3-1d (2:3.14.5-1+deb7u2) installed. So far, I tried a lot of workarounds from everywhere but still fail. Any ideas ?

Comment: What is your ultimate goal here?  Is it to play Steam.  Because even the [Mesa Package Tracker at Debian](http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mesa/) no longer has any of the versions you are requesting and mixing source into a binary based distro is dangerous!!

Comment: It's dangerous for sure, but I also need this for virtualization (iOS and Windows Phone emulators through VMWare Workstation). I just posted the Team Fortress 2 problem since it's the same problem but with more cases over the internet. Does the Mesa Package Tracker you gave me is for Wheezy only ?

Comment: The Package tracker is the mechanism debian uses to manage version changes between upstream and the debian distro across all versions of Debian, not just Wheezy.  The upstream source is [located here](ftp://ftp.freedesktop.org/pub/mesa/), and if you look at the directory structure, the version of 10 that you want is in the `older-versions` subdirectory.  I hate to push this, but Steam is unsupported in Wheezy for the reason you're trying to fix and others.  See the [Debian Wiki - Steam](https://wiki.debian.org/Steam)

Comment: I already have try to compile from upstream starting Mesa > 8.0.5 to 10.0.5. Unfortunately, I can't since during the make process of Mesa, it says that libdrm_nouveau version is 0.6, needed 2.4.33 at least, but that the istalled one is 2.4.40 ! I don't really understand the point of this happening.

Comment: That's because you need to install the kernel headers and other development tools for your version of Debian.  Try `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential`

Comment: They were both already installed when I did make for Mesa. Here's the output for the make process, just look at the first bug report: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/162807/what-are-the-required-build-dependencies-of-mesa-for-debian-based-distros

Comment: I've now asked a question about that error message: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164554 Sorry about the delay.

Comment: No problem. By the way, how is the procedure you follow in order to compile Mesa from snapshot ? I'll make tests and see if I can make something work. I don't care about breaking my Debian since it don't bother me to reinstall it again and again.

Comment: @user3755746 NB: If you don't stick my name in front with an @, I won't be notified. I just happened to come and look at this question. I can suggest workarounds re the mesa snapshot, but I was hoping someone knowledgeable would respond. Where do you suggest I put "the procedure you follow in order to compile Mesa from snapshot"? Since this currently does not work, it is not a complete answer to your question. I think I'll email some Debian developers about this issue and see what they say.

Comment: @FaheemMitha :Oh I see now ^^. Mmm, just put your procedure as the second part of my post, so it will be considered as "what is tried". Unfortunately I've already asked the Debian X Strike Force about the way to correctly compile Mesa and redirected them to this post but got no answers :(. By the way, I didn't asked for the lidbdrm_nouveau question at that moment, maybe they'll answer to you since I may not have correctly formulate my mail.

Comment: @user3755746 Ok, I'll just add a partial answer. Hopefully it won't get downvoted.

Comment: @user3755746 See the build instructions for mesa at the bottom of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/164554/. If you have difficulties with the instructions, add a comment/question. Also, consider changing your user name to something else. Unless you want people to think of you as a number.