# What is the correct way to fix the configure error: "Requested 'libdrm_nouveau >= 2.4.33' but version of libdrm_nouveau is 0.6"?

Tags: debian, debugging

This issue came up when trying to assist a user with the questions: [What are the required build dependencies of mesa for Debian-based distros?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162807) and [How do I backport Mesa on Debian Wheezy?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/162919/).

Mesa on Debian fails to build from source under certain conditions. See the Debian bug report: [libdrm-nouveau1a: claims to be 2.4.33, but seems to really be 0.6](https://bugs.debian.org/668684). I was able to reproduce this building Mesa 9.1.3-1 (from snapshot.debian.org) on Wheezy. I get the following error message:

```
checking for NOUVEAU... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libdrm_nouveau >= 2.4.33) were not  
met:

Requested 'libdrm_nouveau >= 2.4.33' but version of libdrm_nouveau is 0.6

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables NOUVEAU_CFLAGS
and NOUVEAU_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

See [the full log at gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/c0c0d455a2f9951dcedf).

I'm not sure what is going on here. There is an "explanation" in the bug report, but I don't understand it. Namely:

> It's not a bug in the debian libdrm 2.4.33 package. In libdrm git they
>   bumped the soname to 2 and changed the version exported in
>   libdrm_nouveau.pc from 0.6 to 2.4.33 without releasing a new version.
>   Mesa now requires the newer libdrm that hasn't been released yet. In
>   libdrm 2.4.33 the version in libdrm_nouveau.pc is 0.6
>
> http://cgit.freedesktop.org/mesa/drm/commit/?id=292da616fe1f936ca78a3fa8e1b1b19883e343b6
>   is the commit this all took place today.

The file `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libdrm_nouveau.pc` exists on my system. This is a pkg-config file. It has the following contents.

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=${prefix}
libdir=${prefix}/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
includedir=${prefix}/include

Name: libdrm_nouveau
Description: Userspace interface to nouveau kernel DRM services
Version: 0.6
Libs: -L${libdir} -ldrm_nouveau
Cflags: -I${includedir} -I${includedir}/libdrm -I${includedir}/nouveau
Requires.private: libdrm
```

This is presumably where the configure is getting the information that 
`libdrm_nouveau` is 0.6.

However, I'm unclear why the version was set to 0.6 when the actual value is
`2.4.40-1~deb7u2` (Debian wheezy default). I'm also unsure of the correct way to fix this in the current context - building Mesa 0.9.3.1 on wheezy.

There are two obvious changes one could make which would (probably) allow Mesa to build.

1. Change the version number in
   `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/libdrm_nouveau.pc` to 2.4.33 or
   higher
2. Alter the Mesa configure script to accept libdrm at version 0.6.

I don't much like either of these alternatives. In the former case, I dislike messing with a running system. It is never clear what effects it may have. In the latter case, changing a build system without properly understanding what effect it will have does not seem like a great idea either.

**NOTE:** If you want to reproduce the error on Wheezy, you can do the following:

1. go to http://snapshot.debian.org/package/mesa/9.1.3-1/
2. download the files:

   - [`mesa_9.1.3.orig.tar.gz`](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20130529T040126Z/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_9.1.3.orig.tar.gz) (wget -c http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20130529T040126Z/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_9.1.3.orig.tar.gz)
   - [`mesa_9.1.3-1.diff.gz`](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20130529T040126Z/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_9.1.3-1.diff.gz) (wget -c http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20130529T040126Z/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_9.1.3-1.diff.gz)
   - [`mesa_9.1.3-1.dsc`](http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20130529T040126Z/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_9.1.3-1.dsc) (wget -c http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20130529T040126Z/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_9.1.3-1.dsc)
3. Run

   ```
   dpkg-source -x mesa_9.1.3-1.dsc
   ```
4. `cd` into the source directory `meda-9.1.3` and run

   ```
   debuild -uc -us
   ```

   and install missing build dependencies.